# How are ProducerTemplate and Apache Camel routes linked in Spring application?

Tags: spring, rest, apache-camel

I just started working on a Apache Camel with Spring and CXF rest web service and while going through the current code I am not able to understand the few things.

1. Normally for apache camel we need to create a `CamelContext` and then link it to `producerTemplate` and then we add the route to the `CamelContext` like below.

   ```
   CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
   ProducerTemplate template = context.createProducerTemplate();
   context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {public void configure() {
   ...
   }
   ```

   But when I see this in spring application its different, We are creating camel context in XML file with below which will allow spring to search the Spring `ApplicationContext` for route builder instances i.e. Camel pickup any `RouteBuilder` instances which was created by Spring in its scan process.

   ```
    <camel-spring:camelContext id="marriottCamelContext"
            useMDCLogging="true" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
            <camel-spring:contextScan />
            <template id="xxxTemplateProducer" camelContextId="xxxCamelContext" />
        </camel-spring:camelContext>
   ```

   So above is the linking of RouteBuilder with camel context.
2. Now for the producer Template, as in the application we are just creating the object in `@Service` class like below and sending the request to `Route` class

   ```
    @Autowired
    private ProducerTemplate template;

    UpsellResponse upsellResponse = template.requestBodyAndHeaders("{{upsell.route}}", upsellRequest, headers, UpsellResponse.class);
   ```

   But I am not able to understand how the template is linked with Camel Context and Route here. And also want to know whether the first point is correct or not.

I also noticed in the Route Class, `{{}}` are used to in `from({{}})` and `to({{}})` for the property file variable. Is this any specific rule related to Camel since in spring we use to use `${}` for the variable from property file with `@PropertySource and @Value`

E.g  `from("{{upsell.route}}").routeId("v2.upsell.Hystrix.Consumer").to("{{upsell.hystrix.consumer.route}}");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Spring XML files and @Autowire etc then camel-spring has factory beans that create ProducerTemplate and link to CamelContext. Also it has a namespace parser to parse `<camelContext>` and create Camel context.

For using `{{ }}` then its the syntax Camel uses for property placeholders. See more here: http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-use-spring-property-placeholder-with-camel-xml.html and http://camel.apache.org/using-propertyplaceholder.html

Comment: does name of template id matter in the below line of XML

Comment: <template id="xxxTemplateProducer" camelContextId="MarriottCamelContext" />

Comment: Thats the bean id if you want to give it a special name. By default it assigns the name as producerTemplate afair